# How to insert 1d array from two numpy array element by element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I try plotting. I need x axis as time and I write this method. But i couldnt make result like that
`rtctime = np.array([17.02.31, 17.02 37, 17.02.38])`
How to combine rtchour,rtcminute,rtcsecond arrays element by element and When I merge arrays, there is no problem on the x axis of the graph.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import (NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar)

import numpy as np
import traceback

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    rtcdate = np.array([])
    rtchour = np.array([])
    rtcminute = np.array([])
    rtcsecond = np.array([])
    rtctime = np.array([])

    data = np.array([])
  def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.DataReader()

        self.pushButton_data.clicked.connect(self.Graph)

    def DataReader(self):

        graph_data = open("DATA.TXT", "r").read()
        downLines = graph_data.split('\n')

        for line in downLines:
            try:
                if len(line) > 1:
                 valuedate, valuehour,valueminute, valuesecond,\
                 value= line.split(' ')

                 self.rtcdate = np.append(self.rtcdate,valuedate)
                 self.rtchour = np.append(self.rtchour,valuehour)
                 self.rtcminute = np.append(self.rtcminute,valueminute)
                 self.rtcsecond = np.append(self.rtcsecond,valuesecond)
                 self.data = np.append(self.data,value)

            except:
             print("Error:")
             print(traceback.format_exc())
             continue
    def EKGDatas(self):

        self.MatplotWidget.canvas.axes.clear()
        self.MatplotWidget.canvas.axes.plot(self.rtcsecond, self.ekgdata)
        self.MatplotWidget.canvas.axes.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=70)
        self.MatplotWidget.canvas.draw()
       self.window.show()

if __name__== '__main__':
    import sys
    App = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    PrecautionApp = Main()
    PrecautionApp.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# -------------------- matplotwidget.py --------------------
# ------------------------------------------------------
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MatplotWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())

        vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        vertical_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)
```

DATA.TXT

```
30/07/2019 17 02 31 129
30/07/2019 17 02 37 1
30/07/2019 17 02 38 154
30/07/2019 17 02 39 147
```

I am working big project. There are pyqt5 designer code in project.
My goal is to draw the data according to the date and time in the data.txt file. After doing this, I will analyze the graph. Therefore, according to my research I have reached the need to convert my series to numpy. I'll merge it into a single array to display it on the x-axis of the graph (hour.minute.second) and send it to the plot function.

Comment: Don't use the `data=np.array([])` followed by `data=np.append(data,...)` approach.  It is hard to get right, and slow.  Initial a list `alist=[]`, and do `alist.append(...)` in the loop.  It is faster.

Comment: Have you considered using the `datetime` library?

Comment: @BenT  my time datas is come from txt and I am using  this save datas.

Comment: @hpaulj  thank you for suggestion. Please check for me if i misunderstood, Firstly I use adding like array after convert np.array.

Comment: can you post the full code that starts with you defining and initializing the class object... because  rtcdate = np.array([])
    rtchour = np.array([])
    rtcminute = np.array([])
    rtcsecond = np.array([])
    rtctime = np.array([])  should all be defined under def __init__(self): if they are instance variables and you should be writing 'self.rtchour'

Answer (score 0):

One option is to convert to a `datetime` object which `matplotlib` can use for plotting. You might have to rethink how you structure your code but it would greatly simplify what you are trying to do and make sure that when you plot your data your axis is consistent when transitioning from 59 minutes to 1 hour for example.

Something like this would give you your time list:

```
import datetime as dt

graph_data = open("DATA.TXT", "r").read()
downLines = graph_data.split('\n')

timedata = []
for line in downLines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        timedata.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line,'%d/%m/%Y %H %M %S %f'))


print(timedata)
#[datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30, 17, 2, 31, 129000), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30, 17, 2, 37,100000), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30, 17, 2, 38, 154000), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 30, 17, 2, 39, 147000)]
```